# Python TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, int, typeerror, subscript

I am trying to create a ballot system in which a user can input candidates names and then input preference scores. The program then works out the winner and prints a result.

I am getting an annoying return from my console when I run this line of code.

```
for i in range(len(winners)[i]):
```

The error reads:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

*(Edited: Code dump redacted.)*

Comment: What do you think that `[i]` there does?

Comment: *"Need Help Fast !!!"* - this is **not** a helpdesk, please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6506/248731

Comment: @Wolf I removed it because the question is pretty clear without the full dump.  You can fetch the code from the edit history if you are pathologically curious.

Answer (score 1):

You want to iterate over winners:

```
for i in winners:
```

What you were trying to do::

```
for i in range(len(winners)):
```

will iterate through indexes, your error was the `[i]` that have nothing to do here.

Answer (score 0):

The function len returns an integer, which is the length of the array in question. Hence, when you add the subscript `[i]`, you are trying to access an array, which you don't have.

If you want access to all indices, you need to use `for i in range(0,len(winners))`. If you want access to every element of the array, without worrying about the indices, the use `for s in winners`.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Note that `0` is the default `start` argument to `range`, so you can leave it out in this case